# How to populate Lightning Data Table with custom columns and data?

Tags: lightning-web-components, query, lightning-datatable

Say I have a LWC with a Datatable that displays the values of field A in Column 1, and field B in Column 2.

Now I want Column 3 to display the value of Column 1 + Column 2. How would I go about this?

**Context**

- I query a bunch of fields (aggregate results) from an object in an Apex class
- I want to display these values in a datatable's columns, but I also want to display custom columns whose values are math operations based on the field values (like field 1 + field 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do any calculations you want in the wire handler:

```
this.data = result.map(
  value => ({ 
    ...value, // Copy all existing values
    customPercentageOfTrade: value.roundedFeeUnits / value.totalUnitsRequstedDisinvestment,
    // more calculations here
  })
);
```

Note that you're going to want to alias all your calculations and fields, as you cannot traverse field relationships in a lightning-data-table.

For example, this is not allowed:

```
{label: 'Fund Name',fieldName: 'Fund__r.Name', sortable: true, type: 'text'},
```

Because the table is going to look for a field like:

```
{ "Fund__r.Name": "Sample" }
```

And not:

```
{ "Fund__r": { "Name": "Sample" } }
```

You can use the map technique from above to flatten your objects so that all the fields are in a flattened object.

Comment: @user256515 The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) lets you copy one object's values to another, new object, via `{...value}`, and the extra fields thereafter are additions to the new object we're creating.

Comment: @user256515 Yes, you can call it flattening or aliases, the mapping process is the same as what we'd define in math: "associate each element of (a set) with an element of another set." The act of mapping is transforming one value into another. See [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more information on that, too.

Comment: @user256515 `value` contains whatever came by the server (by default); we're defining additional attributes to include in the new clone of the server data.

Comment: @user256515 That looks good to me. Any issues?

Comment: @user256515 wire methods don't fire until after the first render() cycle, so it's your template that's causing an issue. add `if:true={partnerships.data}` and you should be fine.

Comment: @user256515 We'd need to debug this code to find out what the error was. I don't see any reason why you should be getting an error.

Comment: @user256515 Yeah, that's a common mistake, but usually one you'll only make once.  Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: @user256515 setScale is an Apex language feature. Use [`toFixed(precision)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) instead.

Comment: @user256515 Either side is not a number or number-like (you are actually allowed to say `'5' * '10'` to get 50), possibly null/undefined. Make sure you're paying attention to cAsE-sEnSiTiVe variable names. This is often compounded by the fact that Apex isn't case-sensitive, so it's easy to make a mistake.

Comment: @user256515 Your code presumes that, for example, `totalUnits` is a non-zero value (you can't divide by zero!). You might need something more like `customPercentageOfTrade: (value.totalUnits && value.roundedFeeUnits)? (value.roundedFeeUnits / value.totalUnits).toFixed(5): 0`.

Comment: @user256515 this would refer to the class itself, definitely not what you want. And yes, the variables being assigned at the same time would be a problem. You could chain multiple map calls together, or refer to the original `value` object.

Comment: @user256515 That's odd. I'd expect a different error. I suggest you ask a new question on that topic, this chain is already pretty long.